# Flutter Firebase - updating user profile image returns an error while the image change on Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, stream-builder

I have an app with a profile page, where I want to have a profile picture, where the user can update whenever he wants.

The code I have now does the following: a StreamBuilder will get the Firestore collection with the Current User UID, and build an Image.network getting the doc "URL" from the snapshot.data.

**The problem:**

The first time, when the user creates a new user, I have a placeholder on the image, and when the user selects a new image from gallery, it will return an error for the time between updating the collection and updating the UI, and then it changes to the new image. Also, it takes a lot of time to change the image, depending on the size of it.

If someone could give me maybe a different approach on how I am doing, I would appreciate.

**The function to upload to Firestore:**

```
File _image;

  Future getImage(bool gallery) async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile pickedFile;
    // Let user select photo from gallery
    if (gallery) {
      pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        uploadFile(_image);
        uploadToFirebase(); // Use if you only need a single picture
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> uploadFile(File image) async {
    String downloadURL;
    Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("images/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid}");
    await ref.putFile(image);
    downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  }

  Future uploadToFirebase() async {
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");
    final String uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;

    String url = await uploadFile(
        _image); // this will upload the file and store url in the variable 'url'
    await users.doc(uid).update({'url': url});
    final result = await users.doc(uid).get();
    return result.data()["url"];
  }
```

**The code where I am displaying the image:**

```
Container(
                                child: _image != null
                                    ? Column(
                                        children: [
                                          StreamBuilder(
                                            stream: _firebaseFirestore
                                                .collection("Companies")
                                                .doc(_firebaseAuth
                                                    .currentUser.uid)
                                                .snapshots(),
                                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                                AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                                return Text("Loading");
                                              }
                                              return Image.network(
                                                snapshot.data.data()["url"],
                                                width: 100,
                                                height: 100,
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    : Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                        ),
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        child: Icon(
                                          Icons.camera_alt,
                                          color: Colors.grey[800],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Can you let me know if this works?

```
File _image;
bool _loading = false;
final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket:'gs://LINK.com'); //find your link in your storage console like this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/gW35HJk.png
StorageUploadTask _uploadTask;

  Future getImage(bool gallery) async {
    this.setState((){
    _loading = true;
    });
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile pickedFile;
    // Let user select photo from gallery
    if (gallery) {
      pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );
    }
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        uploadFile(_image);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
        this.setState((){
        _loading = false;
        });

      }
    });
  }

  Future<String> uploadFile(File image) async {
    String downloadURL;
    String filePath = "images/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid}";
    setState(() {
      _uploadTask = _storage.ref().child(filePath).putFile(image).onComplete;
    });
    var imageUrl = await (await 
    _uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    downloadURL = imageUrl.toString();
    
    uploadToFirebase(downloadURL);
  }

  Future uploadToFirebase(downloadURL) async {
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");
    final String uid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid;

    String url = downloadURL // this will upload the file and store url in the variable 'url'
    await users.doc(uid).update({'url': url});
    final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

    if (result != null) {
       setState((){
            getImage().onComplete{
            loading = false;
       }
       return result.data()["url"];
    }
    });
  }

----------Below is before edit---------------

Use a bool to determine if loading is complete or not

bool _loading = false;

    Future getImage(bool gallery) async {
        this.setState((){
        _loading = true;
        });
    
        ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
        PickedFile pickedFile;
        // Let user select photo from gallery
        if (gallery) {
          pickedFile = await picker.getImage(
            source: ImageSource.gallery,
          );
        }
        setState(() {
          if (pickedFile != null) {
            _image = File(pickedFile.path);
            uploadFile(_image);
            uploadToFirebase(); // Use if you only need a single picture'
     setState(() {
          _loading = false;
        });
          } else {
            print('No image selected.');
            setState(() {
          _loading = false;
        });
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but still shows the error... to be correct, the error is: The method 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data()

Comment: It's only for the first time yet

Comment: Instead of downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL(); Try the following modification: downloadURL =  await (await ref.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();

Comment: Also in your uploadToFirebase() method, add a setState at the end: setState((){ getImage().whenComplete(() { _loading = false; }); });

Comment: there is no way to add downloadURL = await (await ref.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();  the onComplete does not exist :/

Comment: Oh ok, I might be using an older dependency. What dependency is your firebase storage? Can you try await ref.putFile(image).onComplete; instead?

Comment: I've edited my answer above, it is the code that works for me but using older version of firebase storage. I cant upgrade because it messes up my whole project at the moment, so can you let me know if it works for you? Ignore any onComplete if it doesnt exist

Comment: Ok, Yeah, I am using a newer version of Storage, so the onCompleted method is deprecated... I am looking at some other examples to see what to use instead of it... Looks like I have to await the future, I'm trying to adapt your code now... also, on this part : getImage().onComplete{
            loading = false; Should I say true or false inse getImage(false/true)?

Comment: Looks like the new function is called "Whencomplete" do something, the syntax is a bit different, but should work the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230918/discussion-between-guilherme-jacobus-and-texv).

Answer (score 1):

First, in your code, you are uploading the file twice: once in setState() and again in uploadToFirebase();

You can try to show the loading text while snapshot.connectionState is different from connectionState.done:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
    return Text("Loading");
}

return Image.network(
    snapshot.data.data()["url"],
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
);
```

Comment: Hey, can you give me an explanation on where I am uploading it twice? which SetState are you talking about?

Comment: Also, this code just show the Loading text, does not change to the image :/

Comment: Inside function **getImage()**, 
`uploadFile(_image); <----
uploadToFirebase();  // Use if you only need a single picture`

Comment: Can you try again, now are showing loading if hasn't data.

Comment: Yeah, but the uploadFile and uploadToFirebase do different things, one is to the storage, and the other one is to firestore...

Comment: Hey, just an update... I put a default placeholder in the user collection, so it's alright now, thanks either way!

Comment: Yes, I saw, but in **uploadToFirebase** you are calling **uploadFile** again, so, uploads two times. In your storage the images are not duplicated?

Comment: True, man, I did not realised I was calling it on uploadToFirebase and on getImage, thanks! And btw, no, they are not duplicated, maybe because I am doing it with the UID of the current user?